# How to explain that a man was blessed with a baby?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-request

My manager(male) blessed with baby, my friend is asked why your manager not coming to office. I told:

> *Manager got baby*.

My friend laughed a lot. Is this sentence is wrong? If right in which context I can use.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as proofreading. This is a question asking how to explain that a man is out of the office because his wife just had a child. This is a phrase-request question, not a proofreading question.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed. I agree with @ColleenV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say:

> "My manager has just had a baby"

That would be a perfectly decent way to express the reason why your manager is not coming to the office.

If you use the verb "get" it sounds like your manager "acquired" the baby! Maybe he bought it, found it or did a deal for it. That's not what you want to say and maybe why your friend laughed.

**ADDITION**:
I am a native speaker so saying the above would work fine. As the comments below point out, it might be necessary to clarify to the listener the sex of your manager.

Male manager:

> My manager and his wife have just had a baby.

Female manager:

> My manager has just had a baby.

However, as can be seen on this page, there really are quite a few ways to express this sentiment, so my overriding advice to you would be choose a simple verb (like "have") and concentrate on using grammar correctly to express your message.

Comment: As a native speaker, we say this quite commonly, even when referring to a man, since it is generally understood that men do not "have" babies, in the sense that they give birth to them, but rather that they have a partner/wife/whatever that has given birth.

Comment: @Msfolly If the person you were speaking to didn't know the gender of the manager though, they would probably assume you were talking about a woman. In that situation I might say "My manager and his wife (or partner if they aren't married) just had a baby."

Answer (score 6):

I think when you become a father, you don't say "I got a baby". The verb get is usually used to mean " to receive, acquire, or come in the possession of". I am not a native speaker. I think you should say as follows:

1. My manager just became a  father.
2. My manager has become a father.
3. My manager was blessed with a baby.
4. His wife just had a baby.